# MariaDB rand() query not return 1 row everytime

Tags: mysql

I have a table named hit_counter. It's this

```
CREATE TABLE `hit_counter` (
`id` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
`cnt` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

and I insert some data:

```
insert into hit_counter(id,cnt)
values(1,0),(2,0),(3,0),(4,0),(5,0),(6,0),(7,0),(8,0),(9,0),(10,0);
```

My question is:
I query sql

```
select * 
  from hit_counter
 where id= floor(RAND()*10)+1;
```

The query returns 0 rows or 1 row or 2 rows.

Why does the query not return 1 row every time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `RAND()` function is being executed for *each row* retrieved from hit_counter.

A row is retrieved from `hit_counter`. The value of the `id` column is compared to the result returned from evaluating the expression containing `RAND()`. Each time that expression is evaluated, it returns another value.

If your intent is to evaluate that expression containing `RAND()` just *one time*, and then use the result to find an `id` value that matches, you could use a query like this:

```
SELECT c.id
     , c.cnt
   FROM (SELECT FLOOR(RAND()*10)+1 AS n) i
   JOIN hit_counter c
     ON c.id = i.n
```

When this query runs, the inner query (the inline view definition) is executed one time. The result from the view query (a single row) is materialized into a derived table. And that row remains constant while the outer query runs.

---

The EXPLAIN output for the original query shows a full scan of `hit_counter`

```
id  select_type  table        type    possible_keys  key     key_len  ref       rows  Extra        
--  -----------  -----------  ------  -------------  ------  -------  ------  ------  -------------
 1  SIMPLE       hit_counter  ALL     (NULL)         (NULL)  (NULL)   (NULL)      10  Using where
```

The EXPLAIN output for the re-written query:

```
id  select_type  table       type    possible_keys  key      key_len  ref       rows  Extra           
--  -----------  ----------  ------  -------------  -------  -------  ------  ------  ----------------
 1  PRIMARY      <derived2>  system  (NULL)         (NULL)   (NULL)   (NULL)       1                  
 1  PRIMARY      c           const   PRIMARY        PRIMARY  1        const        1                  
 2  DERIVED      (NULL)      (NULL)  (NULL)         (NULL)   (NULL)   (NULL)  (NULL)  No tables used
```

Notice that the access to `hit_counter` (alias `c`) is by the primary key. This means that the value that the `id` column is compared to is *constant*.

Comment: I have also tried the same query in MSSQL and RAND() seems to be evaluated only once (which I think is a more intuitive).

Comment: Thank you very much!Your analysis is very reasonable. But the mysql and MariaDB's rand function is the same?

Comment: I also tested on mysql (Server version: 5.5.21-log MySQL), the result is the same.  Thank you very much.